# jQuery optional function parameter

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

Here is what I am trying to simplify:

```
rhp_left.find('.first').removeClass("s7").addClass("s4");
rhp_left.find('.second').removeClass("s5").addClass("s3").after(extra);
```

As you can see the second one has `.after(extra)`at the end.
So, I have the following js function:

```
function MY_FUNCTION(a, b, c, d)
{
   rhp_left.find(a).removeClass(b).addClass(c)d;??
}

jQuery(document).on('click', function() {
   MY_FUNCTION('.first', "s7", "s4", d)??
   MY_FUNCTION('.second', "s5", "s3", d)??
});
```

How do I add this `.after(extra)` as an option??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a condition

```
function MY_FUNCTION(a, b, c, d) {
   var elem = rhp_left.find(a).removeClass(b).addClass(c);

   if (d) elem.after(d);
}

jQuery(document).on('click', function() {
   MY_FUNCTION('.first', "s7", "s4");
   MY_FUNCTION('.second', "s5", "s3", extra);
});
```